# Reading from flash in MVC using Flashvars

Tags: flash, model-view-controller, flashvars

An old college of mine made this fancy paperdoll in flash, which i now have to embed on a webpage. I can dres up the paperdoll with hats, shirts, shoes etc.

Each time an item next to the paperdoll is selected, the FlashVars param gets updated.


For example when the "hat" is pressed the following will happened to the FlashVars.

hat0shoe0... ----> hat1shoe0...

And the hat will my visible on my paperdoll.


Is there any way to get that FlashVars out? So i can use it serverside?

I would prefer if i could somehow attach it to my FormCollection, instead of some funcy JS/jquery :)


I hope you can help me out, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actiosncript 3**

To get your flash vars in Actionscript 3 you can do something like: *(untested code)*

```
var myFlashVars:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
//To get boolean (true/false) values
var hat:Boolean = String(myFlashVars["hat"]) == "1" ? true : false;
var shoe:Boolean = String(myFlashVars["shoe"]) == "1" ? true : false;
//or, To get strings ("0"/"1")
var hatStr:String = String(myFlashVars["hat"]);
var shoeStr:String = String(myFlashVars["shoe"]);
```

To send data to a server via Flash/Actionscript 3, you can use URLLoader + URLRequest:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://yoursite.com/yourpage.php");
request.data = "hat=" + hatStr + "&shoe=" + shoeStr; //

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, callWasMade);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, callFailedIOError);
loader.load(request);

function callWasMade(evt:Event):void{
  //Data sent, if needed you can check server response via evt.target.data
}
function callFailedIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
   //Holy crap I can't reach my server!
}
```

**JavaScript**

If you wanted to access the FlashVars via JavaScript and if you are using:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrlStr,,,,,, **flashvarsObj**,,,)
```

As defined [here on the docs](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api)

Why not simply make an ajax call to your server, passing the flashvarsObj you define. Using jQuery, the general idea would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourserverpage.php",
  data: flashvarsObj,
})
```

Comment: This is assuming that you are using ActionScript 3.0 - as you did mention an old college :)

Comment: My experience with flash is very limited, i got provided with a .swf + html to put the paperdoll into my .aspx in my MVC-project.

I was hoping that i somehow could access the FlashVars, somewhere in my Post from the webpage.

Comment: Is it possible to access the FlashVars without using Actionscript?

Comment: The flash vars are first defined in the html of the embeded object, so technically JavaScript could be an option. The way I read your question, ActionScript is the way to do what you want. What other option are you considering in place of ActionScript?

Comment: Im using SWFObject static publishing method atm.
I would prefer using javascript if its possible, since i got some experience there. I cant say that about actionscript.

Comment: see edit and let me know if that was what you were looking for.